# Stack Exchange community to receive feedback about two different frameworks

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Assume that I would like to receive feedback about two different frameworks for Q&A sites. For instance, I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of two different frameworks such as Question2Answer and OSQA.

Is there a place to ask this kind of question in this community? How should I proceed? I mean in our community usually questions about software recommendations are not very welcome. I know about "software recommendations" but even there is not easy to make an on topic question.

Comment: Sounds like slant.co might be a fit? Though take that with grain of salt. I'm a lurker over there. Not an active participant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrased as a comparison, I don't think there's a site in the SE family that will take it, but on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) you could ask for a Q&A framework, which has *a specific set of features you need*, and you would probably (eventually) get both as an answer, both answers mentioning the merits of that particular framework while also considering the feature requirements put in place by the question - assuming people who know about the frameworks find your question. And who knows, maybe you get to know of a better framework you didn't even know of.

See: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question) The answers there should give you further direction.